# How to generate SQL from Case class in ScaLikeJDBC?

Tags: postgresql, scala, scalikejdbc

I have list of case classes, and i want to generate SQL from it.
 So i check the website and found how to reverse engineer the process, which mean from SQL to case classes, and for me , i want to inverse, from the case classes to SQL .

http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/reverse-engineering.html

How can i do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's unsupported. It will take long to support various kinds of RDBMSs. If the library supports it, We need contributors and maintainers of the feature.